# MongoDb: Matching both records missing a Boolean, as well as those that are false

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in my db that may be missing a particular Boolean field.  I need to return the set of documents where either this field is missing or exists, but is false. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I looks like you want a combination of

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/or/

Answer (score 1):

it's possible using [$exists:](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/exists/)

```
db.document.find( { bln : { $exists : true } } );
```

This query will select all documents in the document collection where the bln field exists

```
db.document.find( { bln : { $exists : false } } );
```

This query will select all documents in the document collection where the bln field not exists

Comment: But what about either missing, or exists but false?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript function as a filter in which the current document is `this`. It's not as efficient as using a combination of `$exists` `$or` `$eq` but it allows you to use the familiar JS idiom for testing the falsy-ness (and/or non-existence) of a property:

```
db.myCollection.find( function() { return !this.field; } );
```

More at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/